# Complex Data Type in C Producing Trouble in Algorithm

Tags: c, numbers

I'm trying to perform a calculation which involves the following C-function:

```
long double complex* tridiag_thomas(long double complex *a, long double complex *b, long double complex *c, long double complex *f, int N) {

    long double complex *v; v = (long double complex *)malloc(sizeof(long double complex) * N);
    long double complex *y; y = (long double complex *)malloc(sizeof(long double complex) * N);

    long double complex w;

    int k;

    for (k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        y[k] = 0;
        v[k] = 0;
    }
    w = a[0];
    y[0] = f[0] / w;
    for (k = 1; k < N; k++) {
        v[k - 1] = c[k - 1] / w;
        w = a[k] - b[k] * v[k - 1];
        y[k] = (f[k] - b[k] * y[k - 1]) / w;
    }
    for (k = N - 2; k >= 0; k--) {
        y[k] = y[k] - v[k] * y[k + 1];
    }
    return y;
}
```

I pass a matrix through this function (f), find y, modify f with y, and pass the new f through the function again. I do this on the order of 1000 times. When working with real values (and making the necessary change of long double complex -> long double), this function works as expected. When using it in the above form with complex arguments, however, the result diverges to infinity very quickly.

Can anybody enlighten me as to why that might be? I'm not new to programming, but I am new to C.

Comment: This same thread also is on the computational forum.  By the same user.

Comment: What does this calculation do?

Comment: It solves a matrix equation. For a given vector (f) and tridiagonal matrix (the elements along and around the diagonal being defined by the vectors a, b, c), it solves for a vector y such that the matrix times y is f.

Answer (score 0):

I **do** see a problem where it is leaking 'v'.  This makes me suspect that you are not following the c style assignment at the upper level.  We don't have the upper level code.

When is y freed?  Does the assignment loop through all the values or are you doing a c++ style assignment?  Remember that allocation, assignment, and deallocation do not come for free in c, except for the types built in to the compiler.